# c++ child copy constructor not saving member variable

Tags: c++

I want to create copy constructor only for the derived class as so:

```
  template <typename T>  
  class base_list {
  public:
    base_list() noexcept = default;

    base_list(std::initializer_list<T> il)
    : list_{il} {}

    friend auto operator<<(std::ostream& os, base_list const& sl) -> std::ostream& {
      if (sl.list_.size() == 0) {
        return os;
      }
      for (auto const& element : sl.list_) {
        os << '|' << element;
      }
      os << '|';
      return os;
    }

    auto get_list() const -> std::list<T> {
      return list_;
    }

  private:
    std::list<T> list_;
  };


  template <typename T>
  class derived_list : public base_list<T> {
  public:
    derived_list(std::initializer_list<T> il) : base_list<T>(il) {};

    explicit derived_list(base_list<T> const& other) {
      list_ = other.get_list();

      for (auto const& element : list_) {
        std::cout << "ELEMENT: " << element << '\n';
      }
    }

  private:
      std::list<T> list_;
  };
```

I'm testing it using the below code.

```
    auto bl = q2::base_list<double>{ 1.0, 1.5, 2.0 };
    auto dl = q2::derived_list<double>(bl);
    auto out = std::ostringstream{};
    out << dl;
    auto const expected_output = std::string{"|1|1.5|2|"};
    CHECK(out.str() == expected_output);
```

Can see the elements showing up in the loop but the test fails showing the list is empty... Why isn't the data being saved in list_? Thanks

```
ELEMENT: 1
ELEMENT: 1.5
ELEMENT: 2

....

FAILED:
  CHECK( out.str() == expected_output )
with expansion:
  "" == "|1|1.5|2|"
```

Comment: _"I want to create copy constructor only for the derived class"_ - No, you want the wrong thing. It's unsound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is somewhat analogous to an old-fashioned game of musical chairs.

You have a

```
std::list<T> list_;
```

that's declared as a private member of the `base_list`. And as an extra bonus you also have a

```
std::list<T> list_;
```

that's declared as a private member of the `derived_list`. They happen to have the same name but they have absolutely nothing to do with each other, whatsoever. This would be exactly the same as declaring a `std::list<T> a;` in one, and `std::list<T> b;` in the other. Just because they have the same name doesn't mean they're the same object, they're not, C++ does not work this way. Each class is fully responsible for its class members, and whatever happens in some other class it's derived from, or which derives from it, does not affect it's own class members. They're two different classes. And you've got two different `list_` objects here, each one a private member of its class.

So confusion galore, with two members of classes, with the same name. So, the end result is a game of musical chairs: where will the list of values actually end up?

```
auto bl = q2::base_list<double>{ 1.0, 1.5, 2.0 };
```

This constructs a `base_list`, and the values end up in `base_list`'s `list_`.

```
auto dl = q2::derived_list<double>(bl);
```

This constructs a `derived_list`, and this copies from `list_` in the `base_list` to the `list_` in the `derived_list`. The game of musical chairs has begun. Currently:

`base_list::list_` is empty.

`derived_list::list_` contains the values.

```
out << dl;
```

This calls the `operator<<` overload in the `base_list`, which dutifully shows its own, empty, `list_` as the conclusion to this game of musical chairs.

The constructor is, actually, "saving member variable". The problem is that the `<<` overload is looking at a completely different variable that has nothing to do, whatsoever, with the other variable.